# Types in XQuery

Tags: syntax, xquery, nodes

The node type can be specified as `Node()`

The string type can be specified as `xs:string`

Why is the sytax for node not `xs:node`?

Answer (score 1):

There are mainly two kinds of data types in XQuery: XML native data types and atomic values.

Atomic data types are borrowed from XML Schema, and they put them [in a namespace](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#namespaces) that usually gets the `xs` prefix assigned, which is also [defined in the XQuery specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-datamodel-30/#notation).

I'm not sure about the parentheses of the XML native data types, I guess they origin from XPath's node tests.